# PHP components for PHP based simple and quick framework

Tags: php, components, pear

I want to biuld a simple PHP framework. I have worked in CI and Kohana. And have basic know how of Yii. But I also used Django and really impressed by django. I want to start a small project that is based on Crud or login e.t.c. so I am thinking of creating a small framework with it too. So that in next project I can have better place to start and will definitely add more things next time. There for, I need some components. Basic things that I liked in django is that it don't just generate code like Yii that generate more code that result in larger code base that one need to manage while maintenance. It just render many things from less code. So developer can maintain that less code more easily. While he can simply modify the things by overriding methods that he want.

I don't have much time so I will definitely start from some smaller components that are available. Right now I liked the PHPActiveRecordPattern lib. for db access. I think it use PDO at low level. Now I want to get advise for other components, mentioned below.

1. I want django like or better superb "forms" lib. that I can integrate into my framework. I think I can get some thing from PEAR? with form processor that can be extended with validation.
2. Some login,registration related lib. if there is some thing flexible and good already available. It seems like I need to write it myself based on my requirements although it is simple.
3. Some view and model renderer, to implement simple MVC layers.
4. Some PHP lib. that can generate some files? Although these files will not have much code in them but for basic structures.
5. Some better routing lib.
6. Thumbnail and email classes

While there are already so many frameworks having some of above things, then the purpose of writing my own framework is to have a simple framework, that is quick, simple and that result in less code maintenance overhead at the end of developer. So that one good developer can develop better websites quickly with less overhead, without know different things smarty e.t.c.

Comment: This site has several examples of people expressing the intention to write their own PHP framework, as "it will have less bugs" and "I only need a few functions". Both assertions will turn out to be false in the wide majority of cases, but in each case the OP says they wish to press on regardless! So, @yes123 is quite correct - take the time to learn an established framework. It will save you a _huge_ amount of time in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

"I want create a PHP framework" and "I don't have much time" don't go well togheter. I strongly discourage you to do this.

In 2012 many framework have reached a pretty good level. If you will create your own framework you will just lose time in reinventing the wheel while it's already out there.

Different situation is if you want to do this for learning puropouse, then it's ok.

Comment: I told the above reasons, and also I am not going to have every thing done by myself, at this time, I am just picking the components told above, and will organize them , obviously I don't have as much less time that is not enough to do so. I have less time to writing all the required components by myself

Comment: @Hafiz: I was going to write an answer but I'd be biased towards [lithium](http://lithify.me) you can write an app in a single file and be done with it... then pick what you want. There! I said it!

Comment: @Oerd Ok thanks for your suggestion Oerd, It seems to be a simple framework but I am looking for components that I can integrate